# RUN Alert for ASP LIST ITEMS on dropdownmenu

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script. I need to run an alert each time a language is selected from the dropdown menu. I was able to alert it when spanish is selected (value: es), but I was not able to run the other languages alerts by adding the same scripts. Only spanish was alerting.

Here is the script:

```
<pre>
<b>

<asp:DropDownList ID="aicLanguage" onchange="dropDownListOnChange(this);"  runat="server" name="aicLanguage" Enabled="True">

     <asp:ListItem Value="en" Text="English"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="mn" Text="Chinese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="ja" Text="Japanese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="pt" Text="Portuguese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="es" Text="Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="de" Text="German"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList> )
<pre>
<b>

     <script type='text/javascript'>
         var dropdown = document.getElementById("aicLanguage");
         dropdown.onchange = function (event) {
             if (dropdown.value == "es") {
                 alert(" SPANISH SCHEDULE")
                }
             }
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: No , I just click on the language on the dropdown menu and the alert wont fire .

Comment: Sorry The entire code is not showing up , let me edit the question.

Comment: Do you have ' and/or " in the other-language alert text?

Comment: Have you tried instead of `dropdown.value == 'es'` use `event.target.value == 'es'` in the if statement?

Comment: I just tried it and now only the language on the bottom will fire , let me elaborate a little better my example

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that into a function

```
function go() {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById("aicLanguage");
   var pointer = dropdown.value;
   if (dropdown.value == "es") {
       alert(" SPANISH SCHEDULE");

   }
   //More With other values
   //I would consider using switch statement
 }
```

Then set your drop down to fire that function on change

```
 <asp:DropDownList onchange="go()" id="aicLanguage">   
     <asp:ListItem Value="en" Text="English"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="mn" Text="Chinese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="ja" Text="Japanese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="pt" Text="Portuguese"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="es" Text="Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="de" Text="German"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Using switch statement would help

```
switch(pointer) {
case 'es':
    alert(" SPANISH SCHEDULE");
    break;
case 'en':
    alert("English SCHEDULE");
    break;
default:
    alert("No value defined")
}
```

Noticed how i added a var pointer inside the function and changed it to the dropdown value soi the switch statement knows what variable to perform the switch on

Comment: Sorry I´m just starting to learn Java Script :) , so I´m not quiet sure what a Switch statement is.

Comment: @user5165973 A switch is like a chain of `if` statements, you pass it in a variable and then it will run code based on which of a set of statements it is. This page explains it well: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: I edit my code for an switch example, its easier than chaining if else statements tgether

Comment: I just tried it and I just got the alert("No value defined") when the page was loading.

Comment: I just copy what that "Codepen" had , and YOU GOT IT , thats what I was looking for !! Sorry for my silly question. :)

Comment: How can I give you POINTS or Exposure in this website. (I m also new on the site)

Comment: Sure , how can I do that.

Comment: I believe you click the green checkmark by the "up and down" arrows of my answer

Comment: Done :) , Thanks , I own one :)

Comment: Thanks sir much appreciated